# CSS open calendar on small screen showall and go button show on calendar

Tags: css

Let me firs include image file for better understanding

[image]

What i want that when i click on calendar showall venues and go button no showing on the calendar.How can i do this ?

Comment: You will need to share some actual code with us. We can't just copy a screenshot, no matter how helpful it is.

Comment: what method apply for this ?

Comment: Read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve